# How to fill point background of line chart in chartjs with an image instead of color?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to fill the point background of cricket line graph with a 'w' image. For example, consider a graph of 50overs (x-axis) vs Runs(y-axis). I want to plot a wicket on the graph in point background whenever wicket falls!

Any help welcomed and much appreciated!
Attaching a reference image[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF99o.png)